# Javascript function swfobject.setImage

Tags: javascript, html, flash

i have javascript code in which background image of a SWF object is changed based on button click.

When clicked javascript calls, **swfobject.setImage(imageURL)**

this code works in .JSPA pages but not in html pages (same code is used in both)

in HTML When clicked it throwing error "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'setImage'" in IE

".setImage is not a function" in Firefox,

"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'setImage'" in Chrome